# Pandas DataFrame to_csv writing [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a DataFrame with two columns: a flattened gray-scale image and a label.

After creating the dataframe everything is correct and all images have proper values. When I output to csv, however, it **literally writes the 1d image array as [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0] in the csv**. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

The code roughly consists of the following:

```
images=[]
labels=[]

#Run the following in a loop
image = ndimage.imread(image_file, flatten=True)
image.resize((500,500), refcheck=False)
image = np.ndarray.flatten(image)
label = 'xyz'
images.append(image)
labels.append(label)

#After the loop ends create a dataframe and save it
df_images = pd.DataFrame({'image':images, 'label':labels})
df_images.to_csv('labeled_images.csv')
```

.head() gives the following abridged data:

```
0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  stemmed
1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  stemmed
2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  stemmed
3  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  stemmed
```

a test of length and max values on the dataframe shows it's correctly filled.

Edit: I'm flexible on how to save this to csv, but I would prefer a single column holding the pixel data for the image and a single column holding the proper label for the image. The main goal is to process images and save their pixel values into csv so that I don't have to reprocess and load every time I run a classifier.

Comment: do you really need pandas for this? A pure csv solution could be of interest to you? and do you need the extra counter column that pandas csv adds?

Comment: I would like to load the data into pandas because this involves more data processing and eventually feeds images into an sklearn classifier. I don't need any extra columns, just the image and the label.

Comment: can you include `df_images.head()` in the question?

Comment: the problem here is that you create 2 columns, one for the data (which is a list of lists) and one for the columns. So pandas stores 1 element per column: hence the list. The dataframe is OK, it's just the serialization that is not. Can you [edit] your post to show expected csv output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand a list of 0s and 1s into separate columns, merge them into the original dataframe, and remove the original columns of lists:

```
expanded=pd.concat([df_images['image'].apply(pd.Series), df_images], axis=1)
del expanded['image']
#expanded
#   0  1  2  3   label
#0  0  1  1  0 stemmed  
#1  1  0  0  0 stemmed
```